# Uploading a file into a subdirectory of a Team Drive

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

How may I successfully upload a file to a sub-directory of our team drive? Using the `drive_find()` identifies items in my directory. No matter what I try, the best I can do is get the files to land in the team drive 'root' directory.

I successfully get a list of names, id's and drive resources from this:

```
drive_find(team_drive = 'Data Analytics Team')
```

like so:

```
# A tibble: 29 x 3
   name                               id                                                drive_resource
 * <chr>                              <chr>                                             <list>        
 1 00.ExampleSubDirectory             1XoNCDizzZMHZ4sbBhnCXb-qokk8TW7Q_                 <list [30]>   
 2 df_iris_in-2019-05-01              1kXSD_t96roqeLuXb0BDJfpCejlyZCa6FSL2YtdeWtxE      <list [33]>   
 3 df_iris_in-2019-05-01              1qT_kRff8J8Qu5ZLxZhGLMDB7gO9O1PTtJ_KHsjItgFI      <list [33]>
```

When I attempt to use the example sub-directory id like so:

```
td <- team_drive_get(as_id("1XoNCDizzZMHZ4sbBhnCXb-qokk8TW7Q_"))
```

All I get is this error:

```
Error: HTTP error [404] Shared drive not found: 1XoNCDizzZMHZ4sbBhnCXb-qokk8TW7Q_
  * domain: global
  * reason: notFound
  * message: Shared drive not found: 1XoNCDizzZMHZ4sbBhnCXb-qokk8TW7Q_
  * locationType: parameter
  * location: driveId
```

I get the same results using the url, or the resource id. I have tried everything in the docs here: https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googledrive/googledrive.pdf

How can I specify a path to a subdirectory inside my team drive?

Answer (score 3):

Find the id of the folder you want to write to. It is easiest to navigate to it in the browser. The id is located in the URL.

For example it is `1v4SQb39RTE0MCzrZlLXzxVDB4HPZ8NK7` in this URL: `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/1v4SQb39RTE0MCzrZlLXzxVDB4HPZ8NK7`

Stuff that ID into a googsdrive connecting drive path/socket.

```
drivepath <- drive_get(as_id("1v4SQb39RTE0MCzrZlLXzxVDB4HPZ8NK7"))
```

Write your file to csv, being sure to name the csv what you want the spreadsheet to get labelled (minus the .csv extension). (You can do this in a [tempfile](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4#roundtripping-with-a-private-sheet) but then your googlespreadsheet will end up with the tempfile's name.)

```
write_csv(iris, 'iris_example.csv')
```

Finally push the file up to your desired directory.

```
drive_upload('iris_example.csv', type='spreadsheet', path = drivepath)
```